# Using of watch hook in composition-api?

Tags: vue.js, hook, vuejs3, watch, vue-composition-api

I have the following code in Options API:

```
  ...
  watch: {
    $things: {
      async handler(val, oldVal) {
        this.someFunction()
        if(this.someVariable) this.getSomethingHere()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

How to refactor this code to composition-api using watch hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent Composition API for the `watch` option is [`watch()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch). Assuming `$things` is a [global property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties), use `getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties` to access `$things`:

```js
import { watch, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const someFunction = () => {/*...*/}
    const getSomethingHere = () => {/*...*/}
    let someVariable = true

    const globals = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties
    watch(
      () => globals.$things,
      async handler(val, oldVal) {
        someFunction()
        if (someVariable) getSomethingHere()
      },
      { deep: true }
    )
  }
}
```